# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'low_connectivity_nodes'

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributes, tuples

I am trying to following the 'Pandana network accessibility demo' Github repo (https://github.com/gboeing/urban-data-science/blob/2017/20-Accessibility-Walkability/pandana-accessibility-demo-full.ipynb).

So far, when copying and pasting the code everything was fine but a problem has appeared when I ran this:

```
start_time = time.time()
if os.path.isfile(net_filename):
    # if a street network file already exists, just load the dataset from that
    network = pandana.network.Network.from_hdf5(net_filename)
    method = 'loaded from HDF5'
else:
    # otherwise, query the OSM API for the street network within the specified bounding box
    network = osm.network_from_bbox(bbox[0], bbox[1], bbox[2], bbox[3])
    method = 'downloaded from OSM'
    
    # identify nodes that are connected to fewer than some threshold of other nodes within a given distance
    lcn = network.low_connectivity_nodes(impedance=1000, count=10, imp_name='distance')
    network.save_hdf5(net_filename, rm_nodes=lcn) #remove low-connectivity nodes and save to h5
    
print('Network with {:,} nodes {} in {:,.2f} secs'.format(len(network.node_ids), method, time.time()-start_time))
```

This the error that I am getting:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-693cbbc8dc72> in <module>()
     10 
     11     # identify nodes that are connected to fewer than some threshold of other nodes within a given distance
---> 12     lcn = network.low_connectivity_nodes(impedance=1000, count=10, imp_name='distance')
     13     network.save_hdf5(net_filename, rm_nodes=lcn) #remove low-connectivity nodes and save to h5
     14 

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'low_connectivity_nodes'
```

Comment: Just what it says: `network` is a tuple (a Python predefined data type).  There is no such method for a tuple.  We can't do any more than that, since you failed to supply a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and we have no idea what data type *would* have such a method, or how you thought you were getting one in `network`.

Comment: The notebook uses pandana (v0.2) to download street network and points-of-interest (POIs) data from the OpenStreetMap API (OSM API) and then calculate network accessibility to the points of interest. In case someone could help me, i attached the link to the repo in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this error by doing below

```
network = osm.network_from_bbox(bbox[0], bbox[1], bbox[2], bbox[3])
network=pandana.Network(network[0]["x"],network[0]["y"], network[1]["from"], network[1]["to"],
                 network[1][["distance"]])
lcn = network.low_connectivity_nodes(impedance=1000, count=10, imp_name='distance')
network.save_hdf5(net_filename, rm_nodes=lcn) #remove low-connectivity nodes and save to h5
```